# arcgis arc py add spatial index throws open cursor error

Tags: oracle, arcgis, arcpy

While running  index rebuild using a API (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-spatial-index.htm), i am running into this error.

checked this link : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_open_cursors.htm

it says : If you set open_cursors value too high, you risk having a task abort with the ORA-01000 error

Now, checking the databse  I see 'open_cusrors' parameter setting = 2000  ( using SELECT * FROM v$parameter  WHERE name = 'open_cursors';)

Not sure if 2000 is too high and causing the failure; if I understood the issue correctly we need to 'increase' the open cursor setting to avoid failure - isn't it?  Not sure why Tom says if you set it too high it will fail!

is this causing an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The **open_cursors** parameter is a governor, a block to prevent runaway tasks from consuming too much library cache RAM. Any session may execute many SQL statements and the open_cursors parameter governs the total number of open cursors for any given session.

The value is determined by your application usage. You need to determine whether you need an increase on this value. 2000 is actually high ( default value is 300 ).

Using this query to monitor the usage on your application

```
select a.value, b.name
from v$mystat a, v$statname b
where a.statistic# = b.statistic#
and a.statistic#= 3
```

Don't use v$open_cursors, it can be misleading -- it is cursors that have been opened at some point and may (or may not be) still open. It is useful in helping to track down cursor leaks -- but it shows you more then just "really truly open" cursors.

Setting the value too high might lead to a memory issue, and generally is due to a poor application design.